# Problems using hmailserver as outgoing SMTP server

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, smtp, email-server, hmailserver

I have hmailserver set up and accepting email for projectattack.co.uk domain - I can connect to the server through port 110 pop3 using both gmail and mail.app on osx

I have a cname pointing smtp to projectattack.com and have opened port 25 to accept incoming traffic: smtp.projectattack.co.uk

My server hosting company provide a relay and no auth is required as they only accept messages to relay from ips in their network. This relay has been configured in the administrator app under Delivery of Mail/SMTP Relayer

My server has a static IP

I can't make my email client connect to the hmailserver for the outgoing smtp server.

Is there something above and beyond what i have mentioned here that I need to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smtp.projectattack.com appears to land onto 67.215.65.132 whereas projectattack.com lands onto 109.109.248.82 and neither appears to answer on port TCP 25... You might want to verify your configuration(s) if the intent is to have your clients point to one of the hosts for their outgoing/sending SMTP relay.

Comment: sorry that should be smtp.projectattack.co.uk

Comment: Hmmm... That still looks up to 109.109.248.82, where it is not responding to TCP 25 (SMTP).

Comment: i can actually telnet onto port 25 using smtp.projectattack.co.uk from the server but cant externally. the firewall as port 25 open and my hosting co (tagadab) dont block any ports....

Comment: quickcheck dns seems to think it's ok http://www.checkdns.net/quickcheck.aspx?domain=prjatk.com&detailed=1

Comment: Now it's working where it wasn't a few hours ago. You might try again now with your email clients.